# How to disable a button if it is pressed in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, button, disable

I have been looking at the other tutorials on here to see how to make a button unable to be pressed. However, I keep getting this error:

> 'Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'isEnabled'

The code is:

```
@IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    PlayButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do so by:

```
sender.isEnabled = false
```

Also note that your `@IBAction` function has the same name as the button. This causes a name ambiguity. Change the name of the function to something else.

Comment: And both names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: thank you, if I wanted in another button to turn that off what would I do? I tried putting 'sender.isEnabled = true' but that effects the PauseButton it is under rather than the PlayButton which is disabled. Sorry for asking another question in the comments. @excitedmicrobe

Comment: @rmaddy could you also look at the comment please mate :)

Comment: @Cameron You should post a new question about your new issue. Be sure to include all relevant code and details.